# Rename Qlik Sense Sheets using API

Tags: powershell, rest, qliksense

I am trying to rename Qlik Sense Sheets using APIs. I got to know we should rename only using properties. I tried below code in Powershell but its not working. Please help me correct the code. *I am getting error while retrieving sheets information*

```
$hdrs = @{}
$hdrs.Add("X-Qlik-Xrfkey","examplexrfkey123")
$hdrs.Add("X-Qlik-User", "UserDirectory=INTERNAL; UserId=sa_api")

$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" | Where {$_.Subject -like '*QlikClient*'}

$body = '{}'

$Data = Get-Content C:\ProgramData\Qlik\Sense\Host.cfg
$FQDN = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($($Data)))

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()

# Function to update sheet name
function Update-SheetName {
    param (
        [string]$sheetId,
        [string]$newName
    )

    $body = @{
        name = $newName
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($FQDN):4242/qrs/sheet/$sheetId/properties" -Method Put -Headers $hdrs -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Certificate $cert
}

$apps = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($FQDN):4242/qrs/app/full?xrfkey=examplexrfkey123" -Method Get -Headers $hdrs -ContentType 'application/json' -Certificate $cert

Foreach ($app in $apps) {

    if ($app.published -and $app.stream.name -eq 'SCPM' -and $app.name -eq 'MAERSK Operational Test Rename') {

        # Retrieve list of sheets
        $sheets = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($FQDN):4242/qrs/sheet/full?xrfkey=examplexrfkey123" -Method Get -Headers $hdrs -ContentType 'application/json' -Certificate $cert

        # Iterate through each sheet
        foreach ($sheet in $sheets) {
            # Construct new sheet name with owner name and sheet type
            $ownerName = $sheet.owner.name
            $sheetType = if ($sheet.community) { "Community" } else { "MySheet" }
            $newName = "$ownerName - $sheetType - $($sheet.name)"

            # Update sheet name
            Update-SheetName -sheetId $sheet.id -newName $newName
        }
     }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At C:\Test\RenameSheetName-2.ps1:37 char:13
+ ...   $sheets = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($FQDN):4242/qrs/sheet/f ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: To help other users you could add the error you are getting.

Comment: Included error details. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Update-SheetName` function is using a `$headers` variable while at the beginning of your script you created a `$hdrs`. You may need to use the `-Certificate $cert` part too, as well as the `xrfkey=examplexrfkey123` query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Getting 404 error at $sheets

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At C:\Test\RenameSheetName-2.ps1:37 char:13
+ ...   $sheets = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($FQDN):4242/qrs/sheet/f ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to update sheets using the Repository API. Sheets are part of the app and in order to interact (create, read, update and delete) with its components you'll have to open the app. And this is done via the [Engine API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2024/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/introducing-engine-API.htm). And the Engine API is **websocket** based.